# synonyms of 'just now' in one single word

Tags: vocabulary

I am refining my article in which there's a phrase 'just now'(a little time ago).

It does look less advanced and professional.

Searched dictionaries of Oxford, MW, Cambridge, Collions and dictionary.com.

It has no synonyms.

How to express 'just now' in an advanced way?

Comment: **just now** means something more complex than "a little time ago". It is situational and conversational. Speaker and listener must share the context.  *Did you hear that strange noise in the distance just now?*

Comment: Please give the complete sentence. _Recently_ or _Lately_ could be useful

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to say.  For example, if you want to say that a movie ended *just now* then you could say *"the movie has **just** ended"*.  "Just" is roughly equivalent to the Japanese 「～ばかり」.  However if you mean to say something more complicated, please edit your question to include the entire sentence?

Answer (score 2):

"**Recently**", "**Lately**" or simply "**Now**" could work as one word. "**At this very moment**" and "**right now**" if you mean "**this instance**".

Maybe even "**a second ago**", "**a moment ago**", "**not long ago**", "**a short time ago**", "**a while ago**" or "**only now**" as in "*You can see this effect just now*"

The adverbs "**scarcely**" or "**newly**" could work as "*only a very short time before*":

- *She had scarcely dismounted before the door swung open.*